# How do we visualize magnetic dipole transitons?

Tags: electromagnetism, spectroscopy, dipole

I am studying the transitions between the Kramers doublet sublevels of the ground electronic state of a Co(II) molecular compound. I know that the transitions are magnetic dipole allowed transitions (AKA magentic resonance transitions in this case), but I don't know how to picture them.

**What do the selection rules Δms = 0, ±1 actually mean in a big picture sense?**

A spin change could occur between the ms = ±1/2 and ±3/2 Kramers doublets, giving you a Δms = ±1, but how would you picture a change of zero. Surely there must be something that changes between the two states in that case.